# Why “mistreat” is translated as "三顿饭" by Google translate?

Tags: translation, idioms

In [Google translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=zh-CN&text=mistreat), one of the Chinese translations of “mistreat” is “三顿饭”:

[image]

What does “三顿饭” have anything to do with "mistreat"? Is it an idiom?

Comment: I only have `虐待` on my side

Comment: Haha, I found this too now: "Mistreat me darling and I might just disappear"“三顿饭我，亲爱的，我可能会就此消失” https://www.englisher.net/lyrics/lyric/all-these-strangers/

Comment: @user3306356 will it because of the translation issue ?

Comment: @JohnJoe My first guess, especially based on the context of this question, is that they got it from google. But, even if that is correct, Google must have gotten it from somewhere else. There does exist the idea of “eating” things as a substitution phrase for punishment, e.g.: Sichuanese has 吃笋子熬肉 which literally mean to eat bamboo stewed meat - but figuratively it means “do you want a beating?” So, it is possible that the translation could be correct, but we’d need to see where google got their translation from.

Answer (score 1):

Mistranslation is the cause of this ridiculous translation.

Don't trust Google translate, especially when it comes to Chinese. Just report this mistranslation to Google.

Comment: But This is not an answer for the question.

Comment: Mistranslation is the cause of this ridiculous translation.

Comment: I added your comment (which is really the answer) to your original answer (which was really more of a comment).